# ffmpeg segment to devide video into small chunks

Tags: ffmpeg

hello everyone I want to split my video into small chunks.I am using ffmpeg segment to achieve this and I want to split the video in same video lenght chunks.I am using ffmpeg segment to split the video.I have written the command

```
**ffmpeg -i first.mp4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list out.list SplitVideo/out%04d.mp4**
```

When I am executing this command it splits the video in to small chunks but it is not accurate.The chunks are not of same length

Comment: maybe reask on superuser

Comment: it could be that ffmpeg cut at the closest IDR ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience I realized the following:
Depending on the video format, there are usually dependencies between different frames. It means that some frames are depended on some other frames to be decoded. Therefore the splitting MAYBE cannot be done at any time you want because some of these dependencies might get lost their connections and hence cannot be decoded later. So what ffmpeg does is actually to find the nearest point that is independent from previous frames so all dependencies are satisfied. This will cause different lengths.